# Setting margins dynamically in code - android

Tags: android, dynamic, tablelayout, tablerow, margins

I have an activity which contains only ScrollView and a TableLayout in it. In my code i'm adding tablerows, everything works fine except margins - it's not working (nothing happens) Here is the code:

```
LayoutParams rowparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rowparams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        for (int i = 0; i < obiekty + 1; i++) {
            rowparams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
            trs[i] = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
            trs[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            trs[i].setLayoutParams(rowparams);
            trs[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33B5E5"));

        }

tvs[licznik].setText(nazwa);
            tvs[licznik].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            tvs[licznik].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            iv[licznik].setImageResource(obraz);
            iv[licznik].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBB33"));
            trs[licznik].addView(tvs[licznik]);
            trs[licznik].addView(iv[licznik]);
            tl.addView(trs[licznik]);
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `TableLayout.LayoutParams`

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams rowparams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```