# Programmatically set ImageButton margins

Tags: android

I have create a lot of image button like this code:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
if (db != null) {
        if (db.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);
                int ID = Integer.parseInt(db.getString(db.getColumnIndex("ID")));
                int resource = getResources().getIdentifier("unit" + ID, "drawable", getPackageName());
                System.out.println("unit" + ID + ":" + resource);
                button.setImageResource(resource);
                button.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                tr.addView(button);
                button.getLayoutParams().height = 250;
                button.getLayoutParams().width = 250;
                button.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                //button.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
                rowcount++;
                if (rowcount % 5 == 0) {
                    layout.addView(tr);
                    tr = new TableRow(this);
                }
            } while (db.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

And I found code:

```
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tableRowParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

and apply in button at the do while.

```
button.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
```

It will show the error message "android.widget.TableLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow$LayoutParams"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting margins dynamically in code - android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826067/setting-margins-dynamically-in-code-android)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `TableLayout.LayoutParams` with `TableRow.LayoutParams`:

```java
TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams =
        new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tableRowParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks you, This is my mistake

Answer (score 0):

The type of `LayoutParams` that you use is determined by the container of the view, not the view itself. So since your button is going inside a `TableRow` you need to use `TableRow.LayoutParams` rather than `TableLayout.LayoutParams` as you have it now.

Also, just so you're aware, if you need to style your TableRow or Button, rather than creating a new instance of the class and seeing the margins that way, you can inflate an XML layout using `Button button = (Button) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.button, tr, false);` and that way you can set the margins in the XML file.